# nested where exists takes too long to execute

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

I have the following query which runs fine and does not take much time

let's call it query 1:

```
select t3.date2
      ,t4.date1
      ,case
          when t4.date1 is null then
           t3.date2
          else
           t4.date1
       end check_date
      ,t3.dimension2
  from (select max(date2) date2
              ,dimension2
          from view1 t4
         where measure2 > 0
         group by dimension2) t3
  left join (select max(t1.date1) date1
                   ,t1.dimension1
               from table1 t1
              where dimension2 = 'some value'
                and exists (select 1
                       from (select max(date2) date2
                                   ,dimension2
                               from view1
                              where measure2 > 0
                              group by dimension2) t2
                      where t1.date1 > t2.date2
                        and t1.dimension1 = t2.dimension2)
              group by t1.dimension1) t4
    on t3.dimension1 = t4.dimension1;

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ABOVE QUERY:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                         |
|   1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER              |                         |
|   2 |   VIEW                              |                         |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                    |                         |
|   4 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI            |                         |
|   5 |      VIEW                           |                         |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY                 |                         |
|   7 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                         |
|   8 |         INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN| TABLEB                  |
|   9 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER       |                         |
|  10 |          TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | TABLEA                  |
|  11 |          TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | VIEW1                   |
|  12 |      TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL      | TABLE1                  |
|  13 |   VIEW                              |                         |
|  14 |    HASH GROUP BY                    |                         |
|  15 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER           |                         |
|  16 |      INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN   | TABLEB                  |
|  17 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                         |
|  18 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL     | TABLEA                  |
|  19 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL     | VIEW1                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now by using the previous 'query 1', I'm creating a new query. This query doesn't throw any error but it takes forever to run

```
select a
      ,b
      ,date1
      ,dimension
  from table1 t5
 where some_condition = 'some condition'
   and some_column is null
   and exists (select 1
          from ('query 1 here') t6
         where t5.dimension = t6.dimension2
           and t5.date1 >= t6.check_date);

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ABOVE QUERY:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name                    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |                         |
|   1 |  FILTER                                   |                         |
|   2 |   INLIST ITERATOR                         |                         |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED    | TABLE1                  |
|   4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                      | TABLEC                  |
|   5 |   FILTER                                  |                         |
|   6 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                     |                         |
|   7 |     VIEW                                  |                         |
|   8 |      SORT GROUP BY                        |                         |
|   9 |       HASH JOIN OUTER                     |                         |
|  10 |        HASH JOIN OUTER                    |                         |
|  11 |         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL         | VIEW1                   |
|  12 |         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL         | TABLEA                  |
|  13 |        INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN       | TABLEB                  |
|  14 |     VIEW                                  |                         |
|  15 |      SORT GROUP BY                        |                         |
|  16 |       HASH JOIN SEMI                      |                         |
|  17 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE1                  |
|  18 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TABLE1_N5               |
|  19 |        VIEW                               |                         |
|  20 |         SORT GROUP BY                     |                         |
|  21 |          HASH JOIN OUTER                  |                         |
|  22 |           HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                         |
|  23 |            TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL      | VIEW1                   |
|  24 |            TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL      | TABLEA                  |
|  25 |           INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN    | TABLEB                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have also a similar query as above but in place of 'query 1 here' part I have a much simple query like 'select max(some date), dim from t group by dim' which returns way more data (I am sure about it), but it runs fast and gives me a result, but when combined in the above query, it keeps running forever and I have to manually terminate it

** I am not an oracle/sql developer, I just use select query to fetch data and sometimes when the data returned is too huge, I try to transform it directly in the query to avoid post-processings

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#PFGRF009

Comment: @jarlh what is this, i opened the link not able to understand

Comment: @abeeweeda he is suggesting that you post the execution plan so we have some clue what the issue might be. Table and structure and data volumes and distribution might also help, though I would start by formatting the query to make the nesting levels clearer.

Comment: @jarlh added explain plan